# A fast way to find a row that contains a specific object in a .NET DataTable

Tags: .net, datatable

I have the following scenario:

```
Public Class MyType
{
   Public string A{ get;set;}
   Public string B{ get;set;}
}
.....
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("myNode", typeof(MyType)));
```

What is the most efficient way to locate a row that holds a MyType where A = "specific value" other than doing a for each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datatable.rows has a find() method, however I've never been satisfied with the speed of it if you're dealing with a large datatable or many finds. If you're only dealing with 2 columns of data, have a look at using a hashtable instead. They are VASTLY faster when it comes to searching.

Answer (score 0):

There is Select and find methods for datatable. May be you can use that.

Answer (score 0):

I addition to what Jeff Bane proposed, consider filtering your data at the database level (SELECT ... WHERE ...). For truly gargantuan volumes of data, nothing beats the database.